# R : How to create objects with a function which name and value depend on an argument, and that these objects are found in the global environment?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, return, paste

I have the following situation: I have different dataframes, I would like to be able, for each dataframe, to create 2 dataframes according to the value of one of the columns (log2FoldChange>1 and logFoldChange<-1).

For this I use the following code:

```
DJ29_T0_Overexpr = DJ29_T0[which(DJ29_T0$log2FoldChange > 1),]
DJ29_T0_Underexpr = DJ29_T0[which(DJ21_T0$log2FoldChange < -1),]
```

DJ229_T0 being one of my dataframe.

First problem: the sign for the dataframe where log2FoldChange < -1 is not taken into account.

But the main problem is at the time of making the function, I wrote the following:

```
spliteOverUnder <- function(res){
  nm <-deparse(substitute(res))
  assign(paste(nm,"_Overexpr", sep=""), res[which(as.numeric(as.character(res$log2FoldChange)) > 1),])
  assign(paste(nm,"_Underexpr", sep=""), res[which(as.numeric(as.character(res$log2FoldChange)) < -1),])
}
```

Which I then ran with :

```
spliteOverUnder(DJ29_T0)
```

No error message, but my objects are not exported in my global environment. I tried with `return(paste(nm,"_Overexpr", sep="")` but it only returns the object name but not the associated dataframe.

Using `paste()` forces the use of `assign()`, so I can't do :

```
spliteOverUnder <- function(res){
  nm <-deparse(substitute(res))
  paste(nm,"_Overexpr", sep="") <<- res[which(as.numeric(as.character(res$log2FoldChange)) > 1),]
  paste(nm,"_Underexpr", sep="") <<- res[which(as.numeric(as.character(res$log2FoldChange)) < -1),]
}

spliteOverUnder(DJ24_T0)
```

I encounter the following error:

```
Error in paste(nm, "_Overexpr", sep = "") <<- res[which(as.numeric(as.character(res$log2FoldChange)) > : 
  could not find function "paste<-"
```

If you've encountered this difficulty before, I'd appreciate a little help.
And if you knew, once the function works, how to use a For loop going through a list containing all my dataframes to apply this function to each of them, I'm also a taker.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When assigning, use the `pos` argument to hoist the new objects out of the function.

```
function(){
    assign(x = ..., value = ...,
           pos = 1 ## see below
    )
}
```

... where 0 = the function's local environment, 1 = [the environment next up](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html) (in which the function is defined) etc.

**edit**
A general function to create the split dataframes in your *global environment* follows. However, you might rather want to save the new dataframes (from within the function) or just forward them to downstream functions than cram your workspace with intermediary objects.

```
splitOverUnder <- function(the_name_of_the_frame){
    df <- get(the_name_of_the_frame)
    df$cat <- cut(df$log2FoldChange,
                  breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 1, Inf),
                  labels = c('underexpr', 'normal', 'overexpr')
                  )
    split_data <- split(df, df$cat)
    sapply(c('underexpr', 'overexpr'),
           function(n){
               new_df_name <- paste(the_name_of_the_frame, n, sep = '_')
               assign(x = new_df_name,
                      value = split_data$n,
                      envir = .GlobalEnv
                      )
           }
           )
}

## say, df1 and df2 are your initial dataframes to split:
sapply(c('df1', 'df2'), function(n) splitOverUnder(n))
```

Comment: I don't know where this comes from, but I have this error:
 `Error in get(the_name_of_the_frame) : invalid first argument `
I tried with DJ_T0 and DJ24_T0 which are my first two dataframes...

Comment: Make sure to quote the dataframes' names, i.e.: "DJ_T0" not DJ_T0 .